# how to get the real path of the Uri which handled from whatsApp

Tags: java, android

I tried to copy the files from folder to another all my code works fine, but when I tried to move the file which handled from whatsApp an error happened that is

> column '_data' does not exist

when I handle the file from Media it works fine and the Uri is:

> content://media/external/audio/media/52889

but if the file handled from whatsApp the Uri would be:

> content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/5033

So how can I get the real path of the Uri is coming from whatsApp

here is the Log Cat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

I appreciate any help, and thanks for advance

Comment: you dont need `Uri`'s path, instead you need `Uri`'s `InputStream`, see `ContentResolver` docs on how to get it

Comment: @pskink Can you please provide me by a link, and Thanks for your help

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html)

Comment: @pskink I used the content resolver to open steam like this:  InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(audioUri); but now I need to copy this file to another folder how could I?

Comment: google for: `java copy InputStream`

Comment: I solved it myself ^__^ thanks for your help

Comment: that's good, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an InputStream object of URI received from WhatsApp or any 3rd party app. Doing so enables one to upload the media to a server or perform other tasks.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
```

**Note:-** This must be performed as soon as one receives the intent or in the same base activity.